# What could make personalized keyboard shortcuts stop working

Tags: windows-xp, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcuts

A colleague has asked me to develop a program which he could launch thanks to a keyboard shortcut, do something quick and then close automatically (for instance: put a string of characters in the clipboard).
I have made such a program thanks to AutoIt, created an .exe file, placed it safely somewhere on my computer, created a shortcut to that EXE, opened the properties and created a custom shortcut for it (for instance <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd><</kbd>).
On my computer, it does work, it launches the program, puts my string in my clipboard and then closes.
I have tried the same manipulation on my colleague's PC and it does not work. No customized shortcuts work at all. I tried on Firefox shortcut, to put for instance <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> , but it does not work neither (and that one works on my PC too).

So the question is: what kind of settings could make custom keyboard shortcuts not work on one PC and work on another. Does anyone know or have any idea?

thanks a lot.

Comment: Did you tried running the actual script instead of the compiled EXE ?

Comment: Which version of Windows? Where are the shortcuts located? Are they in the Start Menu, pinned to the Start Menu, pinned to the taskbar...? Try adding a shortcut to the EXE in one of these locations and set a keyboard shortcut for it. See if that works.

Comment: @Lamb I cannot run the script by itself without installing AutoIt on my colleague's computer and that is actually not my intention

Comment: @Karan Windows XP SP3. I tried first with the .Exe located in the "My Documents" folder, then created the shortcut at the same location => did not work. Tried on another software like firefox which is pinned in the "QUick Launch" toolbar => did not work.